# How can I understand int *a[5][5]?

Tags: c, pointers

I got a task to modify the content of a 2-dimensional array `int[5][5]`, I was given the definition `int *a[5][5]` and ordered to use a `int**` (the pointer of a pointer) to handle this task.

I'm now wondering the meaning of this `int *a[5][5]`, how can I understand the meaning of this and similar definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int *a[5][5]` is a 2D array of *pointers*. A pointer-to-pointer can be used to point at any pointer item in this array.

A for how to understand the declaration, everything left of the variable name is the type of each item in the array, in this case `int*`.

You could also use [this site](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+*a%5B5%5D%5B5%5D). It works for many C declarations, but not all.

Answer (score -1):

It is nothing but a `Matrix of Pointers`

In fact there are meny questions on stackoverflow on these. Please refer cdecl.org